# how to set constant series value in excel using apple script

Tags: excel, applescript

How to set the constant series value in excel using apple script.

```
 tell worksheet 1 of active workbook
      set obj to make new chart object at end with properties{ 
                                     left position:120,top:50,width: 120,height:150}  
 set ochart to chart of obj    
      tell ochart
           make new series at end with properties {series values:"={1}"}
      end tell
 end tell

 This script through error(Microsoft Excel got an error:Can't make class series)

Please replay
```

Comment: If you want that somebody replies to your questions you must accept correct answers. If you don't accept correct answers, nobody will be happy to reply to you. Also, please, don't use "please replay" in you questions.

Comment: ok, I am not use "Please replay" keyword in question.

Comment: Hello all, I am waiting your replay.

Comment: Please do not add that you are waiting for users to "reply".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if my syntax is wrong or if this is a bug.

[image: Series]

You would expect to be able to create a new series with a constant by using:

```
set newSeries to make new series at end with properties {name:"tempSeriesName", series values:{50}}
```

However, I have only been able to use a range to create the series:

```
set newSeries to make new series at end with properties {name:"tempSeriesName", series values:"A2"}
```

However, once the series has been created you can update the value with:

```
set series values to {50}
```

My workaround has been to find the first blank cell in column A and populate it with a value. I then use this cell to create the range, update the range with the constant, and then revert the temporary cell to a blank.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
        -- Find the first empty cell and populate it with 1
        set counter to 0
        repeat
            set counter to counter + 1
            set myRange to ("A" & counter as text)
            if value of range myRange = "" then
                set value of range myRange to "1"
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat

        set obj to make new chart object at end with properties {name:"chart1", left position:20, top:88, width:33, height:90}
        set ochart to chart of obj
        tell ochart
            set chart type to column clustered
            -- create the chart with the temporary value
            set newSeries to make new series at end with properties {name:"tempSeriesName", series values:myRange}
            -- update the chart with your constant value
            set series values of newSeries to {50}
        end tell
        set value of range myRange to ""
    end tell
end tell
```

[image: Chart]

Comment: Hi, Your script is run successfully but series value {50} is not set for newSeries.

Comment: It works on my machine running 10.6.8. See the newly posted chart.

Comment: Hi, sorry,I am set wrong value "{50}" but in your script is to set {50}. script is run successfully and set series value is {50} after setting for series value {50}. Thanks for better reply.

Comment: Hi, My next question is, how to set the chart element of chart. I am using this script "set char element chart element 1" this script through error.

Comment: Please ask the question along with all of the relevant details in a separate question.